# Is there a max in the amount of data in an XML file

Tags: xml, csv

Is there a max to the amount of data in an XML file? The reason I ask is that I want to get data from a CSV file which can contain over 100.000 values and send all these values via a XML message.

Comment: Nope, there's no limit to the data.  As a complete aside a point of interest, you can construct malicious XML files to perform a denial of service attack.  See a billion laughs, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion_laughs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but a huge XML file can be hard to handle: libraries that load the whole file in memory before you can access its content could be unusable due to memory constraints.

Comment: Any way to tell with which amount this could be a problem?

Comment: @Luc: It depends by available memory and by the specific library: you have to test.

Comment: Basically, many XML tools/parsers rely on holding the entire document in memory. Some (generally identified as "streaming" tools/parsers) can process it sequentially. Writing applications that process XML sequentially is generally quite a bit more difficult. However, 100000 values (assuming each is under 1Kb) is do-able in memory nowadays.